# smoothWheel.js not working in Chrome

Tags: jquery, mousewheel

I have tried this:
$('body').smoothWheel();

This:
$('html').smoothWheel();

And this:
$(document).smoothWheel();

But nothing works. Page does not scrolling

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

body{

```
overflow:auto;
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
position:relative;
height:100%;
.scroll-container{
   position: absolute;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
```

}
}